# How to get the value(s) of a multi-valued attribute from a form in Alfresco share webscript?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a series of checkboxes to capture input for multi-valued attributes from a the user form. How do I, via the YUI controller, retrieve these attributes especially since the checkboxes don't have an **id** but a '**name**' attribute, so I can't use the Dom.get() method (This would require looping and accumulating the values into an array and would require that I give each checkbox a unique id on the form and some of these have almost 30 checkboxes just for one attribute) so I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve the property using an existing ***YUI/Alfresco.class.method*** API method for the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the [API docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html)? `YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsBy()` should do what you want.